# As3 draw bitmap + copyPixel around mouseX and mouseY

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, bitmapdata

I am doing a magnifying glass effect?

I have a working version. However the performance is not good enough on the tablet.

**What i have done so far:**

I had a ENTERFRAME event on a mouseDown

So it start capture the screen when the mouse click down, and follow the mouseX and mouseY

It works, but the only problem it keep draw the whole stage rather than maybe (300px * 300px) around the mouseX and mosueY. is there a way i can make the draw area according to your mouseX and mouseY. I guess that would help the performance as well. :)

```
e.target.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, startCapture);

function startCapture(e:Event):void{
    var glassWidth:uint=80;
    var glassHeight:int=80;
    var curBd:BitmapData;
    var curBmp:Bitmap;
    var posX:int = _parentStage.mouseX - 40;
    var posY:int = _parentStage.mouseY - 40;

    //-------------------------------------------------------------
    //var subArea:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,500,500);
    //var newBmp:Bitmap = new BitmapData(500,500);
    //var cutoutBmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap( newBmp, PixelSnapping.ALWAYS, true );
    //cutoutBmp.bitmapData.draw( jpgSource, new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -357, -341) , null, null, subArea, true );
    //-------------------------------------------------------------

    bd = new BitmapData(1024, 768, true, 0);
    var subArea:Rectangle = new Rectangle(_parentStage.mouseX, _parentStage.mouseY, 500, 500);
   // bd = new BitmapData(500, 500);
   bd.draw(_parentStage.mc_mainContainer);
    // bd.draw(_parentStage.mc_mainContainer);

    curBmp=new Bitmap(new BitmapData(glassWidth,glassHeight), PixelSnapping.ALWAYS);
    curBmp.bitmapData.copyPixels(bd,new Rectangle(posX,posY,_parentStage.mouseX,_parentStage.mouseY),new Point(0,0));
    curBd=curBmp.bitmapData;

    var ma:Matrix = new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -40, -40);
    glass.name = 'glass';
    glass.alpha = 1;
    glass.graphics.clear();
    glass.graphics.beginBitmapFill(curBd, ma);
    glass.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 35);
    //glass.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 35);
    glass.graphics.endFill();

    //var imageCircle:Bitmap = new _magGlass();
    //trace(_magGlass);
    //glass.addChild(_magGlass);

    if(!_parentStage.contains(glass))_parentStage.addChildAt(glass, _parentStage.numChildren - 2);
    glass.x = _parentStage.mouseX;
    glass.y = _parentStage.mouseY - 75;
}
```

Comment: What is `bd` and why do you draw `_parentStage.mc_mainContainer` to it?

Comment: @atonparker bd is bitmap and _parentStage.mc_mainContainer is the stage pretty much

Comment: In your question you ask why it is drawing the whole stage, could that be the line that is doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where your performance problem is coming from is where you're creating new bitmaps and bitmapdatas and rectangles on every frame.  Instead, just create one or two in the constructor or on click and then reuse them. Since you already have a BitmapData, you can probably just put that on the stage and mask it, rather than using the graphics object in glass. At least pick one approach or the other. Doing both is killing you, performance wise.

Comment: Agree bluebill should move any code that doesn't change during every enter frame out of the handler, no reason to be recreating all these objects or even remaking all these assignments if they don't actual change over the course of time.  If the conditional and/or the addChildAt can be moved out as well that's going to be a costly call.  Basically do as little work in here as possible, because you expect this to execute in the part of CPU time given to your app and for it to execute all code once ever 24th of a second by default, point being every bit counts.